# Unit test when loading things at app run with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need my app to run some configuration at runtime vi an HTTP endpoint.

I wrote a simple service to do that:

```
module.factory('config', function ($http, analytics) {
    return {
        load: function () {
            $http.get('/config').then(function (response) {
                analytics.setAccount(response.googleAnalyticsAccount);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Next, I call this module in a run block of my app module:

```
angular.module('app').***.run(function(config) {
        config.load();
    });
```

All is working well when the app is running but in my unit tests, I get this error: "Error: Unexpected request: GET /config"

I know what it means but I don't know how to mock it when it happens from a run block.

Thanks for your help

**EDIT to add spec**

Calling this before each

```
beforeEach(angular.mock.module('app'));
```

Tried this to mock $httpBackend:

```
beforeEach(inject(function($httpBackend) {

    $httpBackend.expectGET('/config').respond(200, {'googleAnalyticsAccount':});

    angular.mock.module('app')

    $httpBackend.flush();
}));
```

But got:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'stack' of null
        at workFn (/Users/arnaud/workspace/unishared-dredit/test/lib/angular/angular-mocks.js:1756:55)
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'stack' of null
        at workFn (/Users/arnaud/workspace/unishared-dredit/test/lib/angular/angular-mocks.js:1756:55)
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'stack' of null
        at workFn (/Users/arnaud/workspace/unishared-dredit/test/lib/angular/angular-mocks.js:1756:55)
```

**EDIT since update to AngularJS 1.0.6**

Since I've updated to AngularJS 1.0.6, advised by Igor from the Angular team, the issue is gone but now I've now got this one, which sounds more "normal" but I still can't figure out how to make it works.

```
Error: Injector already created, can not register a module!
```

Comment: I also have this error when testing `run()`

Comment: I finally moved it in my Application root controller to make it testable.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I struggled with this error for a little while, but managed to come up with an sensible solution.

What I wanted to achieve is to successfully stub the Service and force a response, on controllers it was possible to use `$httpBackend` with a request stub or exception before initiating the controller. 
In `app.run()` when you load the `module` it initialises the object and it's connected Services etc.

I managed to stub the Service using the following example.

```
describe('Testing App Run', function () {
    beforeEach(module('plunker', function ($provide) {
        return $provide.decorator('config', function () {
            return {
                load: function () {
                    return {};
                }
            };
        });
    }));


    var $rootScope;
    beforeEach(inject(function (_$rootScope_) {
        return $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    }));

    it("defines a value I previously could not test", function () {
        return expect($rootScope.value).toEqual('testing');
    });

});
```

I hope this helps your `app.run()` testing in the future.

Comment: Please note the 'config' decorator is not referring to angular's config stage, but to the factory service OP has named 'config'

Comment: This was written around the time of Angular 1.0.5 so the API could have changed a little since then.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if you are still looking for an answer to this question. But here is some information that might help.

$injector is a singleton for an application and not for a module. However, angular.injector will actually try to create a new injector for each module (I suppose you have a

```
beforeEach(module("app"));
```

at the beginning.

I had the same problem while using Angular, RequireJS, Karma and Jasmine and I figured out two ways to solve it. I created a provider for the injector function as a separate dependency in my tests. For example MyInjectorProvider which provides a singleton instance of $injector.

The other way was to move the following statements:

```
beforeEach(module("app"));
beforeEach(inject(function($injector){
    ...
})
```

inside the test suite description. So here is how it looked before:

```
define(['services/SignupFormValidator'], function(validator){
    var validator;
    beforeEach(module("app"));
    beforeEach(inject(function($injector){
        validator = $injector.get("SignupFormValidator");
    })

    describe("Signup Validation Tests", function(){
        it("...", function(){...});
    });
});
```

After applying the fix it looks like this:

```
define(['services/SignupFormValidator'], function(validator){
    var validator;

    describe("Signup Validation Tests", function(){
        beforeEach(module("app"));
        beforeEach(inject(function($injector){
            validator = $injector.get("SignupFormValidator");
        });

        it("...", function(){...});
    });
});
```

Both the solutions worked in my case.

Answer (score 1):

You should mock every HTTP request with [ngMock.$httpBackend](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock.%24httpBackend). Also, [here is a guide](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.unit-testing).

---

**Update**

You don't need the `angular.mock.module` thing, just need to inject your app module. Something like this:

```js
var httpBackend;

beforeEach(module('app'));
beforeEach(inject(function($httpBackend) {
  httpBackend = $httpBackend;
  $httpBackend.expectGET('/config').respond(200, {'googleAnalyticsAccount': 'something'});
}));
```

In your tests, when you need the mocked http to answer, you will call `httpBackend.flush()`. This is why we have a reference to it, so you don't need to inject it in every single test you have.

Note you will need to load angular-mock.js in order to it work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I do any injection before calling angular.mock.module I get an error saying that the Injector was already created

Comment: Post the related specs, please.

Comment: Thanks for the update and help, just tried your code. It's not working better. Still the same error "TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'apply'; TypeError: Cannot read property 'stack' of null". 

By the way, "module" is not working here ("Property 'module' of object [object Object] is not a function"), have to use angular.module.

Comment: You probably forgot to add angular-mock.js to your test HTML, didn't you?

Comment: Just checked in the Karma's Chrome instance, it's here!

Comment: Might be because your module variable is actually named "module", like this, for instance: var module = angular.module('app', []); Try renaming it.