# Argument 'fn' is not a function, when trying to do unit test with Jasmine and AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I'm trying to do some unit tests with Jasmine in my Angular application, but I'm facing some errors.

**Error**

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module LocalStorageModule due to:
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'fn' is not a function, got string
```

**Spec**

```
describe("testing the controller", function () {

   var $controllerConstructor;
   var scope;

   beforeEach(module('app', ['ngRoute', 'LocalStorageModule']));
   beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope) {
       $controllerConstructor = $controller;
       scope = $rootScope.$new();
   }));

   it("should validate a contact", function () {
       var ctrl = $controllerConstructor('crmContatosCtrl', { $scope: scope });
   });
});
```

**App.js**

```
angular
    .module('app', ['ngRoute', 'LocalStorageModule'])
    .config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
       // My routeProvider here
    }]);
```

I'm not using neither Yeoman nor Karma yet, because this is my fisrt application using Angular.

**Included Files**

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jasmine/jasmine.js"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jasmine/jasmine-html.js"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jasmine/boot.js"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/angular/angular-mocks.js"></script>

<script src="../../Scripts/angular/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/angular/angular-local-storage.js"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/ngStorage.js"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/ng-infinite-scroll.js"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/angular/common.js"></script>

<link href="../../Scripts/jasmine/jasmine.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="../core/app.js"></script>
<script src="../crm/contatos.js"></script>
<script src="contatosSpec.js"></script>
```

Comment: I would suggest you create the Ctrl in the beforeEach

Comment: @sam I think I did it by injection, didn't I ?

Comment: I am speaking about this line : var ctrl = $controllerConstructor('crmContatosCtrl', { $scope: scope });
   try declaring it like scope (var ctrl) and initialise it in the beforeeach

Comment: @sam Oh ok. I did the changes, but return the same error. Something  wrong with my 'LocalStorageModule' dependency.

Comment: My answer didn't help ?

Comment: @sam Help a little, but still with the same issue, I've installed Karma also.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67040/discussion-between-sam-and-lucas-santos).

Comment: Any news ? yousuccedeed ?

Comment: @sam yes, I got it. In my app.js I had a `.run(['authService', function (authService) {authService.fillAuthData();}])`, and when I commented this line, and folow your tips, everything works fine.

Comment: I think it may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15643517/unit-test-when-loading-things-at-app-run-with-angularjs

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think you may simply have a problem with your configuration for the dependencies for the tests. Without Karma I don't know how you do the tests but I guess you have somewhere a configuration file for Jasmine where you specify the files to be included. You have to include all files and you have to include first all the libraries. Be careful with the order and try to respect the same as you have in your html file that you use to run the application.

If the order is wrong the JS will try to execute before the libraries it needs are included. In your case maybe even the whole angular stack.

**Update**

Do not forget that Jasmine works using it's own html file and will not include the libraries you usually use if you do not tell it. And also don't forget to include Angular Mock library , essential for your tests

**Update 2**

Ok I think I found why you have a problem

There is something wrong in this code

```
beforeEach(module('app', ['ngRoute', 'LocalStorageModule']));
```

In angular when you call a module using module('smthg',[]) you are **creating** it, not calling it. You should use this form instead, there is no need to reimport the services that you already included in your main module.

```
beforeEach(module('app'));
```

check the Creating versus Retrieval section of the angular documentation https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module

Comment: Woohoo, this did the trick for me! I was foolishly calling beforeEach(module('app'), []) which seemed to be dropping the dependencies defined elsewhere in my app. Thanks.