# unit testing Module failed to load + karma + ionic angularAngular

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, ionic-framework, karma-runner

Trying to load controller module in unit testing karma + jasmine + ionic Angular 1.5.3.

Module/Controller file

```
angular.module('App.View.Controllers', []).controller('ListController',
function($scope){
$scope._userName = UserService.getUserObject().maxperson;
});

describe("ListController", function(){
var $scope, $controller, ListController;
beforeEach(function () {
module('App.View.Controllers');
});
beforeEach(inject(function(_$rootScope_, _$controller_) {
$scope = $rootScope.$new();
$controller = _$controller_;
ListController = $controller('ListController', {$scope: $scope});
}));
it("has a dummy controller", function(){
expect(2+2).toEqual(4);
});
it('should be defined', function() {
expect(ListController).toBeDefined();
});
});
```

Gives me error:

> Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module App.View.Controllers due to:
>       Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'App.View.Controllers' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
>       http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.3/$injector/nomod?p0=App.View.Controllers
>           at node_modules/angular/angular.js:68:12

It is ionic app. Actually controller loads dependency also but for time sake I have commented it out to make a simple controller loads.

```
package.json file
{
    "name": "karma-2174",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "devDependencies": {
    "@uirouter/angularjs": "^1.0.3",
    "angular": "^1.5.3",
    "angular-mocks": "^1.5.3",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.0.4",
    "karma": "^1.5.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
    "test": "karma start"
    },
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check that you have added all the files in karma.conf.js and also take the example of this link:

In the case of ionic, you have added the main ionic file in karma.conf file

https://scotch.io/tutorials/testing-angularjs-with-jasmine-and-karma-part-1

Comment: Thanks Santosh.  I add all required files by referencing to this article only. Now i have added ionic.bundle.js in karma.conf.js so getting error like module and inject is not defined... I tried adding ionicangular.js which has this angular.module('App.Libs').factory('ionic', function() {
    return window.ionic;
});  then getting Module App.libs is not defined.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-mocks

Comment: Please add angular mocks library for test cases

Comment: yes added './node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js', after loadking ionic.bundle.js. now getting error  Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module undefined due to:
 Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'fn' is not a function, got undefined
 http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.3/ng/areq?p0=fn&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined

Comment: Here is the resolution for same issue you are facing
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509523/argument-fn-is-not-a-function-when-trying-to-do-unit-test-with-jasmine-and-an

Comment: Thanks Santosh. It worked.. one small ques: Do we need to load all modules like (App.Models, App.view.Controllers etc) in beforeEach or just loading App module works for each test cases? Our controller needs different dependencies also to be injected too?

Comment: Might be loading appModules alone is fine fine but your all modules need to be loaded because when application start all module is loaded and it is actual application which you are writing test cases for

Comment: So, Please accept my answer and upvote

Comment: now when i am trying to inject all dependencies in controller it gives error Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'App.Libs' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.   i am just loading only my app module in spec file.    beforeEach( function() {
        module('App');
    }); Please help?

Comment: I will share a working code send me your email Id using Ionic js but might be tomorrow